# Validate different quiz inputs (textarea & radio)

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have multiple quizzes, each quiz consists of multiple questions, each question could be (MCQ, true or false or free text).

questions_types:

```
id | type
1  | MCQ
2  | True or false
3  | Text
```

questions:

```
id | question_en | question_fr | type_id
1  | question 1  | question 1  | 1
2  | question 2  | question 2  | 2
3  | question 3  | question 3  | 3
```

answers:

```
id | answer_en | answer_fr  | question_id
1  | answer 1  | répondre 1 | 1
2  | answer 2  | répondre 2 | 1
3  | answer 3  | répondre 3 | 1
4  | true      | vrai       | 2
5  | false     | faux       | 2
```

Quiz blade:

```
@foreach($questions as $question)
    <h4>{{ $question->question_en }}</h4>
    @if($question->type_id != 3)
        @foreach($question->answers as $answer)
        <input type="radio" name="answers[{{ $question->id }}]" value="{{ $answer->answer_en }}" @if(old("answers." . $question->id) == $answer->answer_en) checked="checked" @endif>
        @endforeach
    @else
        <textarea name="answers[{{ $question->id }}]">{{ old("answers." . $question->id) }}</textarea>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Output:

```
<h4>question 1</h4>
<input type="radio" name="answers[1]" value="answer 1">
<input type="radio" name="answers[1]" value="answer 2">
<input type="radio" name="answers[1]" value="answer 3">

<h4>question 2</h4>
<input type="radio" name="answers[2]" value="true">
<input type="radio" name="answers[2]" value="false">

<h4>question 3</h4>
<textarea name="answers[3]"></textarea>
```

Form request validation:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'answers' => 'required|array',
        'answers.*' => 'required',
    ];
}
```

But it only validates the textarea. It passes even if no radio is checked. All radio must be filled. This is dynamic so I can't specify the count or values to validate. How to make sure all radio inputs are checked?

Comment: You should probably specify that like: `'answers.1' => 'required, boolean',`.

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco the number of questions is not constant. Each test has it's own number of questions

Answer (score 2):

when no radio botton is selected the reqest does not contains the radio even as null value.

in other word if you not select any radio button the request is something like this:

```
"answers" => array:2 [▼
    3 => "hi"
  ]
```

so  `'answers.*' => 'required',` means nothing.

you can select a radio as defalut but I think it's not a good way for quiz.
and you can add a hidden input for each radio button:

```
@foreach($questions as $question)
    <h4>{{ $question->question_en }}</h4>
    @if($question->type_id != 3)
        @foreach($question->answers as $answer)

         <input type="hidden" name="answers[{{ $question->id }}]" value="">

        <input type="radio" name="answers[{{ $question->id }}]" value="{{ $answer->answer_en }}" @if(old("answers." . $question->id) == $answer->answer_en) checked="checked" @endif>
        @endforeach
    @else
        <textarea name="answers[{{ $question->id }}]">{{ old("answers." . $question->id) }}</textarea>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

so in this way the radio bottons will be send even have no value and will be validated